# Performance issue with Cypher and Neo4J using LIMIT

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following query:

```
MATCH
  (per:Person)-[:RELATES_TO]->(f:FOO)
    -[:Function_FOO]->(:ENTRY)
    -[:FLOWS*]->()
    -[:PARENT*]->(call:CallExpr)
    -[:PARENT*]->(:Callee {name:'AAA'})
RETURN DISTINCT call.name
LIMIT 176
```

This runs in 270 ms, but when I change the LIMIT to 177, it runs for ever. Do I need to run the query in another way to stop it from this behaviour?

Here is the Plan

```
----------------
NodeIndexSeek
:Callee(name)
8 estimated rows
210 db hits
209 rows
-----------------
|
|
-----------------
VarLengthExpand(All)
call
(UNAMED170)<-[UNNAMED150:PARENT*]-(call)
8 estimated rows
2896 db hits
1343 rows
-----------------
|
|
-----------------
Filter
call
call:CallExpr
8 estimated rows
1343 db hits
212 rows
-------------------
|
|
-------------------
VarLengthExpand(All)
call
(call)<-[UNNAMED104:PARENT*]-(UNAMED102)
0 estimated rows
2509 db hits
-----------------
|
|
-----------------
Filter
call
none(anon[104] in anon[104] where any(anon[150] in anon[150] where anon[104] == anon[150]))
0 estimated rows
0 db hits
1148 rows
-------------------
|
|
-----------------
VarLengthExpand(All)
call
(UNAMED102)<-[UNNAMED87:FLOWS*]-(UNNAMED72)
0 estimated rows
95379 db hits
-----------------
|
|
-----------------
Filter
call
anon[72]:Entry
0 estimated rows
46189 db hits
1439 rows
-------------------
|
|
-------------------
Expand(All)
call, f
(UNNAMED72)<-[UNNAMED48: FUNCTION_FOO]-(f)
0 estimated rows
2878 db hits
1439 rows
-------------------
|
|
-------------------
Filter
call, f
f: FOO
0 estimated rows
1439 db hits
1439 rows
-----------------
|
|
-------------------
Expand(All)
call, f, per
(f)<-[UNNAMED18: RELATES_TO]-(per)
0 estimated rows
2878 db hits
1439 rows
-------------------
|
|
-------------------
Filter
call, f, per
per: Person
0 estimated rows
1439 db hits
1439 rows
-----------------
|
|
----------------
Distinct
call.name
0 estimated rows
1439 db hits
176 rows
-----------------
|
|
-----------------
Limit
call.name
Literal(176)
0 estimated rows
0 db hits
176 rows
-----------------
|
|
----------------
ProduceResults
call.name
0 estimated rows
0 db hits
176 rows
-----------------
|
|
--------
Result
---------
```

and below is the result of the EXPLAIN command with LIMIT set to 177

```
----------------
NodeIndexSeek
:Callee(name)
8 estimated rows
-----------------
|
|
-----------------
VarLengthExpand(All)
call
(UNAMED170)<-[UNNAMED150:PARENT*]-(call)
8 estimated rows
-----------------
|
|
-----------------
Filter
call
call:CallExpr
8 estimated rows
-------------------
|
|
-------------------
VarLengthExpand(All)
call
(call)<-[UNNAMED104:PARENT*]-(UNAMED102)
0 estimated rows
-----------------
|
|
-----------------
Filter
call
none(anon[104] in anon[104] where any(anon[150] in anon[150] where anon[104] == anon[150]))
0 estimated rows
-------------------
|
|
-----------------
VarLengthExpand(All)
call
(UNAMED102)<-[UNNAMED87:FLOWS*]-(UNNAMED72)
0 estimated rows
-----------------
|
|
-----------------
Filter
call
anon[72]:Entry
0 estimated rows
-------------------
|
|
-------------------
Expand(All)
call, f
(UNNAMED72)<-[UNNAMED48: FUNCTION_FOO]-(f)
0 estimated rows
-------------------
|
|
-------------------
Filter
call, f
f: FOO
0 estimated rows
-----------------
|
|
-------------------
Expand(All)
call, f, per
(f)<-[UNNAMED18: RELATES_TO]-(per)
0 estimated rows
-------------------
|
|
-------------------
Filter
call, f, per
per: Person
0 estimated rows
-----------------
|
|
----------------
Distinct
call.name
0 estimated rows
-----------------
|
|
-----------------
Limit
call.name
Literal(177)
0 estimated rows
-----------------
|
|
----------------
ProduceResults
call.name
0 estimated rows
-----------------
|
|
--------
Result
---------
```

Comment: Can you PROFILE both this query and the query with LIMIT 177, and add the query plans to your description (after expanding all elements of the plan)?

Comment: The one with 177 runs for a long time, I am not sure if it ever finishes, does profile work for sth which is still running?

Comment: For the one that never finishes, use EXPLAIN instead.

Comment: @InverseFalcon, I added the plan.

Comment: @Afshin The `EXPLAIN` plan you provided seems to be for a `LIMIT` of 176, not 177.

Comment: @cybersam no, I checked again, it is for 177.

Comment: The plan has this line: `Literal(176)`.

Comment: @cybersam copy paste issue. I updated that line. The rest is correct.

Comment: My speculation is that the issue comes from [:FLOWS*], which causes too many hits.

Comment: @Afshin You can test that by trying out various upper bounds on the :FLOWS relationships. Is there some upper bounds that makes sense and would give you an acceptable response time?

Comment: Yes, that is what I ended up doing, but I thought maybe there is a way I am not aware of, so I do not need to put a limit.